# what does 2nd label [1st][2nd] in 2Darray meaning eg .char label[11][6]

Tags: c, arrays, char

```
#int main() 
{
    int a, b;
    scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);

    char labels[11][6] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "even", "odd"};
    int labels_index;
    for (int i=a; i<=b; i++) {
        labels_index = i <= 9 ? i - 1 : 9 + i % 2;
        printf("%s\n", labels[labels_index]);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

`when i am changing [6] to [5] i am getting error why is this happening`
1.is this length of char
2. what this 2nd square brackets data means in 2d array i know one for rows and other for colums

Comment: `char labels[11][6]` defines `labels` as an array with `11` elements, each of which is an array of `6` characters. Bear in mind that a string literal is represented in C as an array with a nul terminator  (e.g. `"one"` is represented as an array of four `char`, with elements `'o'`, `'n'`, `'e'`, and `'\0'`.  If you reduce the second dimension to `5`, then the array cannot correctly store `"seven"` or `"eight"` (both have 5 characters, plus the nul terminator). Doing that is not a good idea in C, but is not a diagnosable error according to the standard.  It is a diagnosable error in C++

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In C, strings are a represented as char[]. A string must always end with the last char in the array being a null-character, "\0". The null character has a integer value of 0. In order to declare a string, the size of the string will always be "# character" + "null-character". That's why the code won't run if you change the 2nd number in the array declaration from 6 to 5, since to represent the word "three" as a string you need the character array ['t','h','r','e','e','\0'], which is 6 char long.
2. When you allocate a 2d array, e.g. int arr[a][b], you are allocating a space in memory the size of "size of int" * a * b. In memory, this is represented by one long "strip" of memory. That is why you can index into a 2d array using either arr[x][y] or arr[x*a+y].

The following code prints out the entire 2d block of memory both as characters and integers.

```
/******************************************************************************

                            Online C Compiler.
                Code, Compile, Run and Debug C program online.
Write your code in this editor and press "Run" button to compile and execute it.

*******************************************************************************/

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int row = 11;
    int col = 6;
    //scanf("%d\n%d", &a, &b);

    char labels[11][6] = {"one", "two", "three", "four", "five", "six", "seven", "eight", "nine", "even", "odd"};

    // Header
    printf("\n== labels as char ==\n");
    printf("    ");
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) printf("%-2i ", y);
    printf("\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
    {
        printf("%2i ", x);
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            printf("%2c ", labels[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    // Header
    printf("\n== labels as int ==\n");
    printf("    ");
    for (int y = 0; y < col; y++) printf("%-3i ", y);
    printf("\n");

    for (int x = 0; x < row; x++)
    {
        printf("%3i ", x);
        for (int y = 0; y < col; y++)
        {
            printf("%3i ", labels[x][y]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

The code generates the following output when run.

```
== labels as char ==
    0  1  2  3  4  5  
 0  o  n  e       
 1  t  w  o       
 2  t  h  r  e  e   
 3  f  o  u  r     
 4  f  i  v  e     
 5  s  i  x       
 6  s  e  v  e  n   
 7  e  i  g  h  t   
 8  n  i  n  e     
 9  e  v  e  n     
10  o  d  d       

== labels as int ==
    0   1   2   3   4   5   
  0 111 110 101   0   0   0 
  1 116 119 111   0   0   0 
  2 116 104 114 101 101   0 
  3 102 111 117 114   0   0 
  4 102 105 118 101   0   0 
  5 115 105 120   0   0   0 
  6 115 101 118 101 110   0 
  7 101 105 103 104 116   0 
  8 110 105 110 101   0   0 
  9 101 118 101 110   0   0 
 10 111 100 100   0   0   0
```

As you can see, all character not used by the strings are null-characters, indicating the end of the word.

Answer (score 0):

You are declaring a 2D array of char. 11 rows, 6 columns, and try to initialize it with a string list ("one", "two", ...).

For the "three" entry (3rd row), you will need at least 6 characters - including the terminating nul char ('t', 'h', 'r', 'e', 'e', '\0' ). If you reduce 2nd dimension to 5, it does not fit.